# Excel SQL query to save cells into access (not the whole worksheet)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

how can I save cells into access not the whole worksheet, is there a way to do this? my current SQL query is as follows

```
strSQL="SELECT * INTO stickers  FROM [stickers$] IN '' " _
  & "[Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=C:/testing.xlsm]"
```

For example cells A1 and B1 contain a firstname and surname that only need to be saved

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it!

"test" is the table and "a,b,c,d" are the columns

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test (a,b,c,d)" & _
            "VALUES('" & _
            Data1 & "','" & _ 
            Data2 & "','" & _
            Data3 & "','" & _
            Data4 & "')"
```